Google GA4 Missing data and some metrics are 0 in some months of 2023
I notice a couple issues with Google GA4 that I was hoping to get some insight on.

I am no longer seeing any data from before March 2023. I remember being able to see data from this month and the months prior though. It seems like the data has just disappeared.

From all of March 2023 to May 2023, one of my metrics ("conversions" or rather now "key event") was showing as 0's. After May 2023, the metric is showing up fine, no issues.


Does anyone have an idea on what could be causing this? Thanks!
I checked the data in both the login portal and the GA4 API. Both were showing the same results.

Yup. And that's expected.
You see, GA4 is this great new analytics platform that is basically an upgrade of GA UA. And by no means did it mostly aim the cost reduction. As a result, you now have this glorious data retention concept. A new majestic feature that effectively kills your data if it's too old. Where too old would be 2 months by default or 14 months max unless, of course, you're willing to pay Google around $100k/year for GA 360.
Most corps pretty much choose one of these three options:

Export all their GA4 data to BQ. There's a built-in UI that allows you to link your GA4 data to BQ. In BQ, now you will pay for storage usage. Which is, to be fair, fairly cheap given how light GA's data is even on sites with massive traffic. You'd have to get used to either doing your year over year analysis in SQL, or use a standalone BI tool like Looker, Tableau or Power BI. Optionally, some people also move the data from BQ to something internal to maybe optimize the cost of querying it.
Switch to a better analytics platform. Mostly Matomo if you like to support open-source projects or Adobe Analytics if you need strong enterprise features. There are other options too, of course. Most of these folks still use GA4, but a free version just for some SEO and marketing integrations.
Pay up to Google overlords.

